# Programming exercise?

Tags: java

**I got this exercise, is not a homework**, I just trying to solve:

> We manage a farm with horses that have
>   to work on the field.
>
> A horse has
>
> - a name,
> - a maximum amount of
>     working hours per week,
> - the amount
>     of hours actually worked and
> - a field to indicate if she is lazy or
>     hard-working.
>
> All the attributes of the Horse class
>   are private and they have no setters.
>   Initial values are passed through the
>   constructor.
>
> The Horse class has a method to add
>   one hour of actual work. That method
>   is called every hour (that the horse
>   works). At the begin of the next week,
>   we reset that counter to 0, by calling
>   another method taking no parameter.
>
> A lazy horse cannot work more than 34
>   hours/week, while a hard-working horse
>   can work up to 80 hours.
>
> Code a Horse class that is shielded
>   against wrong working hours data.
>
> Your main method will create an horse
>   and call its methods, but the data
>   must never be corrupted, ie. the
>   working hour limits must be respected.
>   For example, a lazy horse's maximum
>   hours cannot be set above 34 and the
>   number of hours worked cannot be
>   greater than the maximum.
>
> If the Horse class detects an attempts
>   to set incorrect data, the data
>   remains unchanged (and you print a
>   message to help you debugging).

Example of correct data:

```
Name: "Blacky" 
lazy: no
max hours / week = 70
actual hours this week = 61

Name: "Sultan" 
lazy: yes
max hours / week = 30
actual hours this week = 1
```

Example of corrupted data (your code should make such a situation impossible to reach)

```
Name: "Georges" 
lazy: yes
max hours / week = 50 (wrong because lazy horses work max 34h/week)
actual hours this week = 51 (wrong because 51 > 50).
```

This is my code:

```
public class Horse {

    private String name;
    private int maximumAmount;
    private int amountWorked;
    private boolean isLazy;

    public Horse(String name, int maximumAmount, int amountWorked, boolean lasyOrHardworking) {
        this.name = name;
        this.maximumAmount = maximumAmount;
        this.amountWorked = amountWorked;
        this.isLazy = lasyOrHardworking;
    }

    void everyHour(){
        amountWorked = amountWorked + 1;
        System.out.println(amountWorked);

        if((isLazy == true)&&(amountWorked <= 34)){
            resetToZero();
        }
        if((isLazy == false)&&(amountWorked <= 80)){
            resetToZero();
        }
    }

    void resetToZero(){
        this.amountWorked = 0;
    }
}
```

and my main class

```
public class MainHorse {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Horse one = new Horse("Blacky", 34,35,true);
        one.everyHour();
    }
}
```

**my question is how can I get that my method everyhour do the reset method, and in general, what is wrong in my code?**

I hoper you can help me

Comment: Firstly, your formatting is messed up and you have almost no paragraph divisions. For this reason alone I suspect you will not get any answers. Paragraph divisions are very important.

Secondly, I'm not seeing any connection between the instructions and what the code is doing.

Thirdly, I don't understand what you are actual question is. You need to explicitly state what you expect the code to do, and what it is actually doing. 

We aren't going to read your mind.

Comment: I've reformatted your question for you so that it's easier to read. Please try to put a little more care towards the formatting of your questions in the future, especially if they're very extensive. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how can I get that my
>   method every hour do the reset method,
>   and in general, what is wrong in my
>   code?

Try to come up with something with `java.util.Timer`

**Minor details:**

Typos and spelling inconsistencies will come back to bite you someday (less likely in Java than in languages that do not require explicit declaration), you should stick to one correct spelling of the word "lazy".

```
this.isLazy = lasyOrHardworking;
```

Why not use `isLazy` in the parameter as well, instead of `lasyOrHardworking`

```
this.isLazy = isLazy;
```

I think `bool == true` isn't adding any value, this looks better to me:

```
if(isLazy && (amountWorked <= 34))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are doing wrong is calling resetToZero() from inside the everyHour() function.
I would have every hour return a bool to indicate success or failure.  If failure, it doesn't increment the horse's amount worked, but prints the debug message.  The main code could then check to see if it is violating the horses limits.  The main code would also call resetToZero when the week ended.

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to go back to zero, just not to increase the hoursworked. Also, if this isn't homework, you have some freedom, so I would not have independent variables for max hours and lazy - that just gives you an opportunity to get them out of sync. I would use named constants for maxLazyhours and maxHardworkinghours.

Then have a function called IncrementHours that just says

```
if (lazy && hours < maxLazyhours) || hours < maxHardworkinghours)
   hours++;
```

It's simpler, right?

Comment: yeah its simpler, I need to correct my code thanks for answering